# ImportError: conv_relu_cuda.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZN2at15checkAllSameGPUEPKcN3c108ArrayRefINS_9TensorArgEEE

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pytorch

I am getting error, when I try to run 03_train from https://github.com/ahendriksen/noise2inverse. It is giving me this output when I tried to run `# Option a) Use MSD network`.
Error output:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_15770/3472637506.py in <module>
      1 # Option a) Use MSD network
      2 if network == "msd":
----> 3     from msd_pytorch import MSDRegressionModel
      4     model = MSDRegressionModel(1, 1, 100, 1, parallel=multi_gpu)
      5     net = model.net

~/anaconda3/envs/noise2inverse/lib/python3.7/site-packages/msd_pytorch/__init__.py in <module>
     22 import msd_pytorch.errors
     23 from .image_dataset import ImageDataset
---> 24 from .msd_regression_model import MSDRegressionModel
     25 from .msd_segmentation_model import MSDSegmentationModel

~/anaconda3/envs/noise2inverse/lib/python3.7/site-packages/msd_pytorch/msd_regression_model.py in <module>
----> 1 from msd_pytorch.msd_model import MSDModel
      2 import torch.nn as nn
      3 
      4 
      5 loss_functions = {"L1": nn.L1Loss(), "L2": nn.MSELoss()}

~/anaconda3/envs/noise2inverse/lib/python3.7/site-packages/msd_pytorch/msd_model.py in <module>
----> 1 from msd_pytorch.msd_block import MSDModule2d
      2 from torch.autograd import Variable
      3 import numpy as np
      4 import torch as t
      5 import torch.nn as nn

~/anaconda3/envs/noise2inverse/lib/python3.7/site-packages/msd_pytorch/msd_block.py in <module>
      1 import torch
----> 2 import conv_relu_cuda as cr_cuda
      3 from msd_pytorch.msd_module import MSDFinalLayer, init_convolution_weights
      4 import numpy as np
      5 

ImportError: /home/aknahin/anaconda3/envs/noise2inverse/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conv_relu_cuda.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZN2at15checkAllSameGPUEPKcN3c108ArrayRefINS_9TensorArgEEE
```

Anyone please help me to solve this error.

Comment: You can find out about this error by just searching for the error message. Concerning the cause, it would help if you provided a [mcve]. However, I'd also search for according bug tickets, maybe there are existing fixes available.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I tried to find solution from google. But it seems none get exact error. But, it gave me an idea is my msd_pytorch version is not compatible with cuda version. When I tried to install msd_pytorch in method mentioned in their  git repo, it took forever.